# Reboot under Win7 when C# program exits

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-7, directx, reboot

I really need help on this. I have a C# program using .NET 4.0, a MySQL database and some DX code. Sometimes when the program exits, the computer reboots. I get no entries in the event log, have no idea what can cause the reboot.
It happens on most Win7 (32 bit) machines, never yet under XP, never yet on my Win7 (64 bit) developer machine.

Any pointers how I can start to tackle this problem? I'm kinda lost without event logs...

Comment: Perhaps some objects are not being disposed propery. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It might be bluescreening, and thus rebooting. Is there a memory/kernel dump? Can you try enabling a kernel dump, and see if it creates a dmp file??

Comment: If you're new to post mortem analysis, channel 9 has a great video series on the topic: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools

Comment: Hi,thanks for the hints. I'll hopefully get a dump tomorrow and run it through dumpchk.exe. Will let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I ran memory.dmp through dumpchk.exe and got the answer: "Probably due to Epsce.sys."

That makes sense, I use Epson's virtual port driver to talk to a POS printer. Will update that driver (it's outdated, version 5) and only re-open the question if the problem persists.

Thanks for the replies!